# HTML drag and drop API questions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement drag and drop using HTML drag and drop API. I want textbox, radiobutton, check box, drop down and file upload button as draggable. I have plenty of problems with the below code.

1. I'm able to drag text boxes, but I'm not able to drag radio button and check box.
2. When I drop a textbox, it is taking it's own position. It is  not taking the exact position where I dropped.
3. When I drag a text box, it's no longer there. Instead I want a copy of the text box to be dragged.

```js
function dragStart(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
  ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target, 0, 0);
  return true;
}

function dragEnter(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  return true;
}

function dragOver(ev) {
  return false;
}

function dragDrop(ev) {
  var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
  ev.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400i,500');
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* Toggle Styles */

#viewport {
  padding-left: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}


/* Sidebar Styles */

#sidebar {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#sidebar header {
  background-color: #263238;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 52px;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar header a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar header a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#sidebar .nav {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div id="viewport">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar">
      <header>
        <a href="#">My App</a>
      </header>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </li>
        <li>
          <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" runat="server" Text="Radio button" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" runat="server" Text="Check box" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" runat="server" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        </li>
        <li>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="content" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondrop="return dragDrop(event)" ondragover="return dragOver(event)">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-notifications text-danger"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Test User</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#content</code>.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you update the code so that the form fields are not ASPX code, just ordinary HTML. It sounds like you are creating a "form designer". Maybe the elements dragged do not have to be form fields, just placeholders for the different elements?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dragging the form field itself you can use a parent element like the `<li>` and make that draggable. Make the drop area a single element without elements that are not part of the drag/drop functionality. The first parameter in `setDate()` is a MIME type. So, in your case just a plain text.

When dropping you can (should) make a clone of the original element, so that you can add more form fields of the same type. You can also insert some completely different code. I guess that you need some UI for changing the name of the form field (like the text input need to be named "address" or whatever). So, you could insert a small form that takes that input.

```js
const nav = document.getElementById('nav');
const formfields = document.getElementById('formfields');

nav.addEventListener('dragstart', ev => {
  ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
});

formfields.addEventListener('dragover', ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
});

formfields.addEventListener('drop', ev => {
  let ul = ev.target.closest('ul');
  let li = ev.target.closest('li');
  let src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  let clone = document.getElementById(src).cloneNode(true);
  clone.removeAttribute('id');
  clone.removeAttribute('draggable');
  ul.appendChild(clone);
  if(li){
    ul.insertBefore(clone, li);
  }
  ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400i,500');
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* Toggle Styles */

#viewport {
  padding-left: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}


/* Sidebar Styles */

#sidebar {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#sidebar header {
  background-color: #263238;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 52px;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar header a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar header a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#sidebar .nav {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div id="viewport">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar">
      <header>
        <a href="#">My App</a>
      </header>
      <ul id="nav" class="nav">
        <li draggable="true" id="text">
          <label>Text<input type="text" disabled></label>
        </li>
        <li draggable="true" id="radio">
          <label>Radio button<input type="radio" disabled></label>
        </li>
        <li draggable="true" id="checkbox">
          <label>Checkbox<input type="checkbox" disabled></label>
        </li>
        <li draggable="true" id="file">
          <label>File<input type="file" disabled></label>
        </li>
        <li draggable="true" id="textarea">
          <label>Textarea<textarea disabled></textarea></label>
        </li>
        <li draggable="true" id="date">
          <label>Date<input type="date" disabled></label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="content">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-notifications text-danger"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Test User</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#content</code>.</p>
        <ul id="formfields" style="min-height:2em; border: solid black thin;padding-bottom:1em;">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I replaced with your code. I'm not able to drop. Do I need to modify something?

Comment: @Ram that is hard to say. Maybe there is something with the order of JS and HTML. And you don't have any errors in your dev tools in the browser?

Comment: Presently the clone is disabled. How can I enable the clone?

Comment: @Ram (as long as you have the clone object) something like `clone.querySelector('input').disabled = false;`

Comment: This works. But a small problem. I'm not able to drop Textarea. All other form fields work. Strange

Comment: clone.querySelector('textarea').disabled = false; When I add this line none of the form fields are droppable.

Comment: @Ram I'm sorry, but I can't help you debug your code. I can only encourage you to use the dev tools in your browser. And if you run into issues ask a new question on SO.

Comment: You have already helped me a lot. Thank you so much for that.